# Определение в Route контроллера, который находится в папке

Tags: laravel

Как в роутах определить контроллер который находится в папке 
`Static`?

Пытаюсь вот так, но он не находит папку:

```
Route::get('/', 'stet/Site__Controller@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у контроллера есть namespace, то пишешь с ним
`Route::get('/', 'namespace\Controller@method');`,
если нет  - то не важно в какой он папке -
`Route::get('/', 'Controller@method');`,

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Site;

Comment: Route::get('/', 'namespace\Site__Controller@index');

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\namespace\Site__Controller does not exist
Выдает

Comment: слово namespace уберите `Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\Site__Controller@index');`